# Difference between creating a property or a link

Tags: relationship, orientdb

I am a newbie at orient-db. I am currently using 1.5.1, but will upgrade to 1.6 shortly.

I've seen two examples of creating a link between two classes, where class `A` has a 1:N relationship with class `B`.

One was via the `CREATE LINK` command, and the other was using the `CREATE PROPERTY LINKSET` on class `A`.

What are the differences between these two methods? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link is one cardinality, linkset is multiple cardinality. Look at the documentation: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Concepts#relationships